# How to remember formatting options for cells in a gridview

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, cell

I'm using a GridView that is bound to an object (an entity).  The grid can be filtered and otherwise customized in terms of the data it shows.  The rows, columns and more specifically cells will be formatted using some rules, but also from the user specifically setting formatting options.

My questions is about the best way to recall the chosen formatting for specific cells.  Currently my best method is to store an id for each cell that looks up all of the formatting for that cell (i.e. ForeColor, BackColor, FontWeight etc).

Another way would be to create a new table (called say Formatted_Cells) that stores the id and column name of the table in question, and then the formatting options.  This would involve checking the Formatted_Cells table each time a cell is processed to check for formatting.  It is quite a bit of processing (similar to the above method).  If I did this I could flag any rows that have custom formatting, and if they do not I wouldn't need to check the Formatted_Cells table which does provide an advantage over remembering formatting for EVERY cell, when the vast majority will not have any custom formatting.

Is there a better way?  I don't think I can use Serialization to help as the grid is loaded from the database which may be modified elsewhere.  But perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Please tag if it is winforms or asp.net and show what you've tried.

Comment: I'd say use the additional table. It's loads of work but your asking for crazy detail here... Why would anyone want to specify formatting for every cell?

Comment: They wouldn't - but they might add formatting for any cell in particular so I need to be able to trace it.  Additional table is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest an additional table also.

Two possible solutions come to mind:

1- Do the formatting in two passes. First load the grid normally, then read Formatted_Cells table from database, find styled rows in grid and apply special styling.

2- When quering database for Cells, add Formatted_Cells table with left join. When loading grid, check for additional columns that might come from left join, apply those. If no additional columns, style normally.